# Replace all items by condition in php array

Tags: php, arrays, numbers

I have a php array like:

```
$arr = [-1, 15, 6, 44, 9292, -2, -776, -6];
```

In fact any array with negative values.

And now I want to change all negative values to another value, let's say 0. 
And in result I want to get this:

```
$res = [0, 15, 6, 44, 9292, 0, 0, 0];
```

How can I achive this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this lib

https://github.com/apollonin/numphp

and use the command

`$arr[$arr->lt(0)] = 0;`

Comment: wow, that's interesting. array_map, as all suggested looks ugly, honestly. I'll check this one

Comment: @JanetDou  first time heard that `array_walk()` looks ugly. Using extra library for such simple task is not a very good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) function to parse array values:

```
<?php

$arr = [-1, 15, 6, 44, 9292, -2, -776, -6];
$newArr = [];
array_walk($arr, function ($item, $key) use (&$newArr) {
    $newArr[$key] = $item >= 0 ? $item : 0;
});

print_r($newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
    if ($arr[$i] < 0)
       $arr[$i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to elaborate on your answer on why this solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

you can use `array_map`

```
$arr = [-1, 15, 6, 44, 9292, -2, -776, -6];

function neg($a){

    return ($a > 0 ) ? $a : 0;

}

print_r(array_map("neg",$arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_walk` function:

```
$arr = [-1, 15, 6, 44, 9292, -2, -776, -6];
array_walk($arr, function(&$v, $k) {
    $v = ($v <0) ? 0 : $v;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Array_walk is great but foreach is faster and easier to understand

```
$arr = [-1, 15, 6, 44, 9292, -2, -776, -6];

foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    echo $value < 0 ? 0 : $value;
}
```